# What is wrong with my sqlite3 CASE statement?

Tags: android, sqlite, case

My code follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(_id) AS count FROM general WHERE _id = 1 CASE WHEN count > 0 THEN UPDATE general SET userGivenId = 'xxx' WHERE _id = 1 ELSE INSERT INTO general (userGivenId) VALUES ('xxx' ) END
```

With the error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CASE": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(_id) AS count FROM general WHERE _id = 1 CASE WHEN count > 0 THEN UPDATE general SET userGivenId = 'xxx' WHERE _id = 1 ELSE INSERT INTO general (userGivenId) VALUES ('xxx' ) END
```

This is the shortest query I will use. Why I do this is because my other queries will have rows that needs to be updated but some may not be touched. Using replace will replace all the data (at least that is how it works for me on my Android phone). For instance my File class will have a filePath, but sometimes the response from the server will return null and I am only to update the File IF the server returns a new File.

Did I forget to write anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have any control logic because this would not make sense in an embedded database (there is no separate server machine/process whose asynchronous execution could improve performance).
`CASE` can be used only for expressions, not for entire commands.

Handle the control logic in your app:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT 1 FROM general WHERE _id = 1", null);
if (c.moveToFirst())
    db.execSQL("UPDATE general SET userGivenId = 'xxx' WHERE _id = 1");
else
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO general (userGivenId) VALUES ('xxx')");
```

For these particular commands, if you have a unique constraint on the `_id` column (and a primary key is constrained to be unique), you can use the [INSERT OR REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) command:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO general(_id, userGivenId) VALUES(1, 'xxx')
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked good. My INSERT OR REPLACE did not work because I was not using a unique constraint.